# How can the navigation bar title be set as the item's name upon tapping on a specific item?

Tags: swiftui, uinavigationbar, swiftui-navigationlink, lazyvgrid

I'm creating a dinner menu with various food item's that can be tapped. Each item is wrapped in a `NavigationLink` that leads to it's detail page.

How can the item's name be placed as the navigation bar title for each item? Here's the entire `MenuItemsView` struct and a gif to demonstrate where I'd like the food item title just as in the previous `Menu` screen.

```
struct MenuItemsView: View {
    let food = (1...12).map { "Food \($0)" }
    let drinks = (1...8).map { "Drink \($0)" }
    let dessert = (1...4).map { "Dessert \($0)" }
    
    let columns = [
        GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 80))
        ]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
                ScrollView {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Food")
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leadingFirstTextBaseline)
                            .font(.title)
                            .padding(.init(top: -5, leading: 16, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                        LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 5.0) {
                            ForEach(food, id: \.self) { item in
                                NavigationLink(destination: MenuItemDetailsView()) {
                                    VStack {
                                        ColorSquare(color: .black)
                                        Text(item)
                                        
                                    }
                                    .padding(.init(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: 0, trailing: 10))
                                }
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                    VStack {
                        Text("Drinks")
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leadingFirstTextBaseline)
                            .font(.title)
                            .padding(.init(top: -5, leading: 16, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                        LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 5.0) {
                            ForEach(drinks, id: \.self) { item in
                                VStack {
                                    ColorSquare(color: .black)
                                    Text(item)
                                }
                                .padding(.init(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: 0, trailing: 10))
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                    VStack {
                        Text("Desert")
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leadingFirstTextBaseline)
                            .font(.title)
                            .padding(.init(top: -5, leading: 16, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                        LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 5.0) {
                            ForEach(dessert, id: \.self) { item in
                                VStack {
                                    ColorSquare(color: .black)
                                    Text(item)
                                }
                                .padding(.init(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: 0, trailing: 10))
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Menu")
                .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                    Button(action: {
                        print("Edit button pressed...")
                    }) {
                        NavigationLink(destination: MenuItemsOptionView()) {
                            Image(systemName: "slider.horizontal.3")
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
}
```

[Food Details Demonstration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8uRW.gif)

As a bonus, if anyone can tell me how to properly line up the `Color Squares` with their respective category name and `Menu` title, I'd appreciate it a lot lol. Thanks!

Comment: The button you are seeing is not the title. It's a back button used to pop into your Menu screen.

Comment: @NiravD Sorry, bad demonstration. I was moving the mouse where I wanted the food item title, in the same spot as the previous screen's menu navigation bar title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out this issue. Here's how:

I passed in `itemName: item` as a `NavigationLink` parameter as the destination. In the `MenuItemDetailsView` file, the body was set up with a `Text` view and `navigationBarTitle` modifier with `itemName` passed in. `itemName` was created above the `MenuItemDetailsView` struct before being passed of course. Here is the `MenuItemDetailsView` and `MenuItemsView` code that solved the problem as well as a quick demonstration:

`MenuItemDetailsView`

```
import SwiftUI

struct MenuItemDetailsView: View {
    var itemName: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(itemName)
            .navigationBarTitle(itemName)
    }
}

struct MenuItemDetailsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let food = (1...12).map { "Food \($0)" }
        
        return Group {
            ForEach(food, id: \.self) { item in
                NavigationView {
                    MenuItemDetailsView(itemName: item)
                }
                .previewDisplayName(item)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`MenuItemsView`

```
import SwiftUI

struct ColorSquare: View {
    let color: Color
    
    var body: some View {
        color
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    }
}

struct MenuItemsView: View {
    let food = (1...12).map { "Food \($0)" }
    let drinks = (1...8).map { "Drink \($0)" }
    let dessert = (1...4).map { "Dessert \($0)" }
    
    let columns = [
        GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 80))
        ]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
                ScrollView {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Food")
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leadingFirstTextBaseline)
                            .font(.title)
                            .padding(.init(top: -5, leading: 16, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                        LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 5.0) {
                            ForEach(food, id: \.self) { item in
                                NavigationLink(destination: MenuItemDetailsView(itemName: item)) {
                                    VStack {
                                        ColorSquare(color: .black)
                                        Text(item)
                                        
                                    }
                                    .padding(.init(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: 0, trailing: 10))
                                }
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }...more code
```

[Food Item Nav Title Solved Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwIcv.gif)

Answer (score 0):

```
@State itemname:String

var body: some View {
...
.navigationTitle(){
Text(itemname)
}
```

Comment: Can the food item name created within the `LazyVGrid` and for each loop be placed inside a state variable? That was my initial thought but couldn't get it to work. @andylee